# MHL with Nexus 4?

Tags: nexus-4, external-display

I know that the Nexus 4 has Slimport technology, which is very close to MHL but draws little/no power. However, is the Nexus 4 still able to use an MHL to HDMI adapter?

Comment: You should edit your question to remove shopping recommendation part. It is off topic here.

Comment: Josia: I just did what roxan correctly suggested, to prevent your question from being closed as off-topic. You can re-edit it anytime if you feel something missing/unclear.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [Specs at GSMArena](http://www.gsmarena.com/lg_nexus_4_e960-5048.php) mention *TV-out (via MHL A/V link)*, which suggests it should work.

On the other hand, [ExpertsReview](http://www.expertreviews.co.uk/smartphones/1296010/google-nexus-4) states:

> The micro USB port also doubles up as a display output, though surprisingly it doesn't use the MHL standard that we've seen on numerous recent devices, such as the Samsung Galaxy S3. Instead it supports the new SlimPort standard, which is based upon DisplayPort.

Which suggests the standards are incompatible (other sources I consulted underline this). An even clearer hint you'll find in a [review by anandtech](http://www.anandtech.com/show/6499/hands-on-with-the-analogix-slimport-microusb-to-hdmi-and-vga-adapters):

> When I wrote that review it wasn't immediately clear what advantages SlimPort offered over MHL, which has become relatively ubiquitous in the year or so since its introduction. Since then I've acquired the SlimPort microUSB to HDMI 1.4 SP1002 and VGA (D-SUB) SP2002 adapters from Analogix for testing out SlimPort on the Nexus 4.
>   ...
>   As of this writing, the Analogix SP1002 adapter is available [on Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B009UZBLSG) for around $30 USD. I haven't seen the SP2002 available online anywhere yet, however.

As this shows, there're SlimPort adapters available which are not *that* expensive (though not *that* cheap either), and are probably better fitted for your purpose. As you either yet have to buy the cable, I'd rather go for the right one.

Comment: Good luck with it -- glad I could help! Once you have used it, maybe it would be a good idea to mention in another comment how well it worked.

Comment: Indeed, that is a pretty good idea.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that MHL is not supported, but its cousin SlimPort is, according to [here](http://www.slimportconnect.com/slimport-supported-devices/) and explained [here](http://blog.clove.co.uk/2012/11/02/what-is-slimport/).

I have not bought yet, but I guess Chromecast might do the trick anyway for more recent devices.

Comment: We have used the chromecast to cast android application and it was not usable. The refresh rate was several seconds. Now I seek for an adapter.